# Issue with API with char* return being caught by IntPtr in P/invoke

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I am trying to P/Invoke a C++ API returning a char* which is a string in C#. I know this should be caught by IntPtr then convert the pointer to string using the Marshaler like so,

C++ API

```
char* WINAPI MY_API(const char *basebuf, char *strbuf)
{
  return targetfunction(basebuf, strbuf);
}
```

C# P/Invoke

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] 
internal static extern IntPtr MY_API([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string basebuf,
                                     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), Out] byte[] strbuf);
```

C# Wrapper

```
public string MY_API_WRAPPER(string basebuf, out string strbuf)
{
     byte[] strbufTemp = new byte[256]; 

     IntPtr ret = MY_API(basebuf, strbufTemp); 
     string retstr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ret); 
     strbuf = MyDataConverter.ByteToString(strbufTemp);  

     return retstr;
}
```

The out parameter string is OK. but the returned string (converted from IntPtr) is garbage.

I can modify the C++ API to allocate the char* to Task Memory then free it in the C# Wrapper, but changing the native code was not an option. also it has a risk of memory leak if the API was used without the wrapper.

i was wondering what happened to the pointer when the API call ended?

Comment: How is the return value allocated?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the return value of "targetfunction" is a pointer to the elements of basebuf. something like this (char* ret = (char*)&basebuf[0])

Comment: That's not going to work then. That's a temporary buffer managed by the pinvoke marshaler. Not valid after the unmanaged function returns. You'll need to marshal basebuf manually.

Comment: So you simply get back what you already passed in.  Note that the argument is *const*, the function promises that it does not modify the string.  So you do not care at all about it, simply ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David, i was able to fix my problem. Since the return value of the function is a pointer to the basebuf parameter, it acquires garbage value when the function returns.

The basebuf should be an IntPtr not a string for the IntPtr return to get the correct value after the call. So it should be P/Invoked like this.

C# P/Invoke

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] 
internal static extern IntPtr MY_API(IntPtr basebuf,
                                     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), Out] byte[] strbuf);
```

C# Wrapper

```
public string MY_API_WRAPPER(string basebuf, out string strbuf)
{
     byte[] strbufTemp = new byte[256]; 
     IntPtr basebufPtr = Marshal.StringtoHGlobalAnsi(basebuf)
     IntPtr ret = MY_API(basebufPtr , strbufTemp); 
     string retstr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ret); 
     strbuf = MyDataConverter.ByteToString(strbufTemp);  
     Marshal.FreeHGlobal(basebufPtr);
     return retstr;
}
```